# Same Node JS http request get ECONNRESET on one server and OK on another

Tags: node.js, http

I've wrote a server which uses express. It is in AWS. I have a clone of it also in AWS.
I try to use those implemented REST API from an example in Node JS:

```
var http = require('http');
    var data = JSON.stringify({
    });

    var options = {
        timeout: 180000,
        host: server,
        port: '80',
        path: restAPI,
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            'Accept': "application/json",
            'Cache-Control': "no-cache"
        }
    };


    var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
    });
    req.on('error', function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
    req.write(data);
    req.end();
```

If I use server 1 has 'server' it works perfect. In contrast, if I use server 2 it doesn't work returning ECONNRESET Socket Hang up. From the server side both servers answer the API with a 200. If I use an example which runs from the browser it works perfect with BOTH servers.

It looks as an issue in Node JS (v4.4.7 in all servers and clients). Anyone can point me to a workaround. I accept changing the way I'm doing the requests, may be using another module.

Comment: It's unclear what your are having a problem with. ECONNRESET means the otherside closed the connection.

Comment: Let me clarify. You have the exact same code running on two severs, and one server is closing the connection. That's neither NodeJS related, nor Programming related. If you think it's an issue with Node 4.4.7 (highly unlikely), and are asking for a work-around, upgrade to Node 6.x.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the .write. Removing it is working now. The difference between one server and the other was that the 1st server was connected through CloudFlare while the 2nd was direct. Connecting the 1st server directly was failing in the same way the 2nd did.
Now, all is working. Thank you very much for your NO HELP Alan. You are one of those who try to point to people instead of helping. Thank you for making the world better every day! You're awesome!